# Angular Jasmine: Unit testing a method that is calling a service without doing actuall http call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, jasmine, mocking

I'm pretty new to unit tests in Jasmine and Angular, so please bear with me :)

I am trying to write a unit test for a method that shoud return an object of type `ArtworkDetail`, but don't want the service to do an actual http call. I heard about mocking data and mocking services, but I'm not sure how to do it myself. Do I make a mock object in my unit test file or do I create a mock service? Any pointers are appreciated!

**app.component.ts**

```
public setArtworkDetail(id: string): void {
  this.details = undefined;

  this.artworksService.getArtworkDetail(id)
    .subscribe((detailData: ArtworkDetail) => {
      this.details = detailData;
    });
}
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        IndexComponent,
        DetailsComponent,
        NavbarComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: ArtworksService, class: MockArtworksService}
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should return an ArtworkDetail when calling setArtworkDetail()', (() => {

  ...

  }));
```

**artwork-detail.model.ts**

```
export interface ArtworkDetail {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  url: string;
  year: number;
  description: string;
  artist: string;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're correct in stating that you want to use a mock. Angular actually has a nice [tutorial page on it](https://angular.io/api/http/testing/MockBackend)

The general gist is that you provide this class in the before methods and then have it return relevant data. IMO the best example from that page is:

```
  it('getHeroes() should return some heroes', fakeAsync(() => {
       let result: String[];
       this.heroService.getHeroes().then((heroes: String[]) => result = heroes);
       this.lastConnection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
         body: JSON.stringify({data: [HERO_ONE, HERO_TWO]}),
       })));
       tick();
       expect(result.length).toEqual(2, 'should contain given amount of heroes');
       expect(result[0]).toEqual(HERO_ONE, ' HERO_ONE should be the first hero');
       expect(result[1]).toEqual(HERO_TWO, ' HERO_TWO should be the second hero');
     }));
```

To verify a certain method was called you need to create [a spy](https://angular.io/guide/testing). Once that is created you can simply call

```
expect(ArtworkServiceSpy.setArtworkDetail.calls.count())
      .toBe(1, 'spy method was called once');
```